# Display time in dojo datagrid

Tags: timezone, xpages

I'm using rest viewJsonService to get data for a dojo datagrid. Time values are shown in Z-Time.

How to get / dispaly the localtime?

Hubert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a formatter parameter to your column

```xml
  <xe:djxDataGridColumn
     id="djxDataGridColumn7"
     field="created"
     formatter="formatTime">
  </xe:djxDataGridColumn>
```

define the formatter code in a client side JavaScript Script Library dojoDataGrid.js

```js
require( [ "dojo/date/locale" ]);

function formatDate(value) {
    return value ? dojo.date.locale.format(new Date(value), {
        formatLength : "short",
        selector : "date"
    }) : "";
}
function formatDateTime(value) {
    return value ? dojo.date.locale.format(new Date(value), {
        formatLength : "short"
    }) : "";
}
function formatTime(value) {
    return value ? dojo.date.locale.format(new Date(value), {
        formatLength : "short",
        selector : "time"
    }) : "";
}
```

and embed it as resource in your XPage with

```xml
  <xp:this.resources>
      <xp:script
         src="/dojoDataGrid.js"
         clientSide="true">
      </xp:script>
   </xp:this.resources>
```

You might also have a look at my [EntwicklerCamp 2014 presentation](http://www.leonso.de/images/Events/SchickMitGridKnutHerrmann.pdf) at page 14 or Marky Roden's blog [Dealing with Dates, and localization in XPages](http://xomino.com/2014/01/14/dealing-with-dates-and-localization-in-xpages/).

Answer (score 0):

Checkout moment.js.  It is a super useful javascript library for dealing with anything time/date related.

http://momentjs.com/